# how to handle the ping exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, ping

I am getting the error `System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException` for the following code.

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
PingReply stats = ping.Send(IPAddress.Parse("8.8.4.4"));
if (stats.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    if(net)
        textBox1.Text = "connected"; 
    else 
        textBox1.Text="Not connected";
}
```

Can anybody tell whats wrong here?

NOTE : the error occurs on line 2

Comment: Are there any exception details?

Comment: Look at the message in the `Exception`, it should give you more information. Also, what line is the error occurring on?

Comment: Wrap the code in an exception (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9031630/543538), what is the exception message? Saying it just throws an exception isn't enough to go on.

Answer (score 2):

To handle exceptions insert your code in a try catch statement like this:

```
try {
    //code here
} catch (PingException e) {
    //Error handling
}
```

Comment: interestingly I put it exactly there and it did not get caught! any opinion on that?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation for `Ping.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx.aspx):

> `PingException`
>   An exception was thrown while sending or receiving the ICMP messages. See the inner exception for the exact exception that was thrown.

So, you need to debug this and inspect the inner exception value to find out *why*. We can't do that for you.

Comment: The bad thing about the PingException is: Most of the things could easily be in the Result. Why should PingReply have a result for DestinationUnreachable if an Exception is thrown that remote pc is unreachable...